# PLotly two thresholds in Bullet Charts

Tags: r, plotly, bullet-chart

Is it possible to have 2 trehsolds in a bullet charts? Currently I can only get 1 threshold

I have added a second threshold line but it wont get added to the plot:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "number+gauge+delta",
  gauge = list(
    shape = "bullet",
    axis = list(range = list(low, high)),
    steps = list(
      list(range = c(0, 25), color = "#0072B275"),
      list(range = c(75, 100), color = "#E69F0075")),
    bar = list(color = "#CC79A7"),
      threshold = list(
      line = list(color = "#0072B2", width = 2),
      thickness = 0.75,
      value = lowerthr),
    threshold = list(
      line = list(color = "#E69F00", width = 2),
      thickness = 0.75,
      value = upperthr)),
  delta = list(reference =  high),
  value = val,
  domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
  title= list(text = "Test"),
  height = 150)

fig
```

Comment: see: https://plotly.com/r/bullet-charts/